# How to add tuples to list after reading from a text file in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, readfile

I am trying to create a program in Haskell that reads text from a text file and adds them to a list.

My idea is:

```
type x = [(String, Integer)]
```

where the String is each word from the text and Integer is how many times that word occurs in the text. So I want to create a tuple of those values and add it to a list. I then want to print the contents of the list.

I know how to read a text file in Haskell, but am unsure as to what to do next. I am new to programming in Haskell and have predominantly been programming in Java which is very different.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have so far from the suggestions. I am able to write to an output text file with the text received from the file and make it lower case. The issues I am having is using the other functions because it says:

```
Test.hs:14:59: Not in scope: ‘group’
```

Here is the code:

```
import System.IO  
import Data.Char(toLower)

main = do  
       contents <- readFile "testFile.txt"
       let lowContents = map toLower contents
       let outStr = countWords (lowContents)
       let finalStr = sortOccurrences (outStr)
       print outStr

-- Counts all the words
countWords :: String -> [(String, Int)]
countWords fileContents = countOccurrences (toWords fileContents)

-- Split words
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords s = words s

-- Counts, how often each string in the given list appears
countOccurrences :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
countOccurrences xs = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sortOccurrences xs

-- Sort list in order of occurrences.
sortOccurrences :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sortOccurrences sort = sortBy sort (comparing snd)
```

Please can anyone help me with this.

Comment: You should break down the problem into smaller steps. And then you probably want to use `Data.Map`.

Comment: first note that `x` is not a valid type-name (needs to be upper-case) - also I think this might be homework (I apologies if it is not) so I don't want to spoil to much, but a *list* is not a very good choice here (as you have to update it a lot) - maybe have a look [*maps*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map.html) instead - also you must have thought of something - no clue at all?

Comment: *spoiler* if maps are to complicated you might use a function `String -> Integer` instead - you can update this with `addOccurence f word = \w -> if w == word then f w + 1 else f w` I found this easier to start with (*please note* that this might not be very efficient - but it's simple) - also look for **folds** (`foldr`, `foldl`, ...) - maybe you can use those somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell features a fairly expressive type system (much more so than Java) so it's  a good idea to consider this issue purely in terms of types, in a top-down fashion. You mentioned that you already know how read a text file in Haskell, so I'll assume you know how to get a `String` which holds the file contents.

The function you'd like to define is something like this. For now, we'll set the definition to `undefined` such that the code typechecks (but yields an exception at runtime):

```
countWords :: String -> [(String, Int)]
countWords fileContents = undefined
```

Your function maps a `String` (the file contents) to a list of tuples, each of which associating some word with the count how often that word appeared in the input. This sounds like one part of the solution will be a function which can split a string into a list of words such that you can then process that to count the words. I.e. you'll want something like this:

```
-- Splits a string into a list of words
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords s = undefined

-- Counts, how often each string in the given list appears
countOccurrences :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
countOccurrences xs = undefined
```

With these at hand, you can actually define the original function:

```
countWords :: String -> [(String, Int)]
countWords fileContents = countOccurrences (toWords fileContents)
```

You now nicely decomposed the problem into two sub-problems.

Another nice aspect of this type-driven programm is that [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) can be told to go look for functions for a given type. For instance, consider the type of the `toWords` function we sketched earlier:

```
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords s = undefined
```

[Feeding this to Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String%20-%3E%20%5BString%5D) reveals a nice function: [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) which seems to do just what we want! So we can define

```
toWords :: String -> [String]
toWords s = words s
```

The only thing missing is coming up with an appropriate definition for `countOccurrences`. Alas, [searching for this type](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BString%5D+-%3E+%5B%28String%2C+Int%29%5D) on Hoogle doesn't show any ready-made solutions. However, there are three functions which will be useful for coming up with our own definition: [`sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort), [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) and [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

1. The `sort` function does, what the name suggests: it sorts a list of things:

   ```
   λ: sort [1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,3]
   [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3]
   ```
2. The `group` function groups consecutive(!) equal elements, yielding a list of lists. E.g.

   ```
   λ: group [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3]
   [[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
   ```
3. The `map` function can be used to turn the list of lists produced by `group` into a list of tuples, giving the length of each group:

   ```
   λ: map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) [[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
   [(1,5),(2,2),(3,2)]
   ```

Composing these three functions allows you to define

```
countOccurrences :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
countOccurrences xs = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort $ xs
```

Now you have all the pieces in place. Your `countWords` is defined in terms to `toWords` and `countOccurrences`, each of which having a proper definition.

The nice thing about this type-driven approach is that writing down the funciton signatures will help both your thinking as well as the compiler (catching you when you violate assumptions). You also, automatically, decompose the problem into smaller problems, each of which you can test independently in `ghci`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I wanted to create the types that I needed to get a clear idea of what I needed to do.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that I now have, please would you be able to look at it and see where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I have got it working now. I had to import Data.List. Another issue is that the tuples are being sorted by word and I want them to be sorted by occurrences. How would I do that?

Comment: @JamesMeade: You can apply the same logic. If you want to sort the words by occurrence, you might be looking for a function like `sortByOcc :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]`. A function you may find useful in this context is [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy).

Comment: I thought so, that is exactly what I have tried. I did:

        `sortOccurrences :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]` `sortOccurrences sort = sortBy (comparing snd)`

I just don't think that the function is correct. What do you think?

Comment: @JamesMeade I think your function looks just fine (except for the fact that you should pass the `sort` argument to `sortBy`, too).

Comment: Like this `sortOccurrences sort = sortBy (comparing snd sort)` ?

Comment: @JamesMeade No; `comparing` takes just one argument. `sortBy` takes two however.

Comment: Okay thank you, please can you look at the updated code in my question. This is what I now have which I know is wrong because I am getting errors. I have tried different ways with passing arguments for the sortOccurrences function, but still get errors. Can you please see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @JamesMeade You're still passing two arguments to `comparing`: `snd` and `sort`. The `comparing` function takes just one argument though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77195/discussion-between-james-meade-and-frerich-raabe).

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Map` is the easiest way to do this.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

-- assuming you already have your list of words:
listOfWords :: [String]

-- you can generate your list of tuples with this
listOfTuples :: [(String, Integer)]
listOfTuples = M.toList . M.fromListWith (+) $ zip listOfWords (repeat 1)
```

Comment: Is this similar to Map<?,?> in Java?

Comment: @JamesMeade I think so. `Data.Map` is a map from keys to values. `Map.fromListWith <function>` lets you make a map from a list of key,value tuples `[(Key, Value)]`, and the function you provide is a combining function to use on the values in case of key collisions. So in this case we pass in `+`, and use key collisions to count up occurrences.

Comment: I see, yeah that is the same format as a Map<Key,Value> in Java. Thank you for the clarification and the suggestion.